# Which is the better way of getting significantly correlated features with respect to outcome variable?

Tags: python, correlation, statsmodels, bonferroni, pingouin

I have a dataset with 2112 features and 2337 entries.
I am trying to see the correlation between these features and the dependent variable. All of the features and the outcome variable are numeric. The features have been standard scaled.
I am trying to use bonferroni correction to get the number of features significantly correlated to the outcome variable.

The first way I am trying is :

```
from pingouin import power_corr

alpha = 0.05/2112
power_r = power_corr(n=2391,power=0.80,alpha=alpha,alternative="greater")
# power_r = 0.2

r = []
count = 0
indices = []
p_vals = []
# x is the matrix containing the features
# y is outcome variable
for i in range(x.shape[1]):
    coef,sign = pearsonr(x[:,i],y)
    if sign < alpha and abs(coef) >= power_r:
    # check if the correlation co-efficient is greater than the computer power_r and the 
    # associated p values is less than the computer alpha
        count+=1
        indices.append(i)
    r.append(coef)
    p_vals.append(sign)
```

`power_r` gives the minimum correlation coefficient above which the correlation co-efficent should be in order to even be accounted for significantly correlated.

If I print `count` I get 1361 i.e 1361 features are significantly correlated with the outcome variable.

However, if I use the generated `p_vals` of `pearsonr` and feed it to

```
from statsmodels.stats.multitest import multipletests
rejected, p_adjusted, _, alpha_corrected = multipletests(p_vals, alpha=0.05, method='bonferroni', is_sorted=False, returnsorted=False)

np.sum(rejected) # 1501 features that are significant
```

So which is the better way of finding significance in correlation in here ?
Or am I compating apples to oranges here ?

Comment: This is a tough question, I'm assuming the usage of bonferroni is to prevent false positives? When you say with "respect to outcome variable" I assume you're looking for strictly supervised methods? Have you tried other models like LASSO and PLS? I think those would be strong candidates for your problem.

Comment: @Simon, I am using Lasso in subsequent steps. I usually look for collinearity as a step so  I wanted to see how it performs here.